# Нужно заменить середину строки на число длины самой строки

Tags: java, строки

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Имею строку

> This string has (len) characters.

Нужно `(len)` заменить на длину самой строки. В данном случае это 33.
Пишу код, но в итоге получается:

> This string has (33) characters.

Остаются круглые скобки. Не могу понять что делаю не так. Вот код:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Open the input stream.
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

       // Put your code here. 
       // For sample (Read the line)
       String s = sc.nextLine();
       String d = String.valueOf(s.length());
       int pos1 = s.indexOf("(");
       int pos2 = s.indexOf(")");
       String b = s.substring (pos1,pos2+1);
       String c = s.replaceAll(b, d);
       System.out.println(c);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте взглянуть на решение своей задачи немного иначе. Воспользуемся регулярным выражением.

```
   String s = "This string has (len) characters.";
   String d = String.valueOf(s.length());

   String string = s.replaceAll("[(][a-zA-Z]*[)]", d);
   System.out.println(string);
```

[На выходе](https://ideone.com/xiyrYF)

```
This string has 33 characters.
```

Опять же значение длины будет неправильным, потому что измеряем

```
"This string has (len) characters."
```

и длина `(len)` не равна длине `33`

Можно сделать так

```
   String s = "This string has (len) characters.";
//измерим длину входной строки без заменяемой части
   int lengthWithout = s.replaceAll("[(][a-zA-Z]*[)]", "").length();
//сложим длину без заменяемой части с длиной вставки
   String string = s.replaceAll("[(][a-zA-Z]*[)]", String.valueOf(lengthWithout + String.valueOf(lengthWithout).length()));

   System.out.println(string);
```

На выходе будет реальное значение

```
This string has 30 characters.
```

Comment: спасибо! прохожу курс на stepik.org. ругается на Ваш ответ, ничего конкретного не пишет почему-то, просто выдает wrong answer

Comment: @Alexander Gninenko, достаточно и такой регулярки `(\\(.+\\))`.

Comment: Друзья, Вы ошибку в коде ищите, а не принципиально другое решение предлагайте.